# Marketing Cloud Connect: Cannot proceed when trying to 'Start Wizard'

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, trailhead

Follow step by step on this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/units/finish-mc-connect-configuration).

I am stuck on this part where it instructs us to :
'10. Click Start Wizard to begin the setup wizard.'

The error message I got is as below :

> Remote Site Setting Missing
>   Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID faultactor=

As shown in this screenshot :

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session ID usually refers to the login session, so I would (1) Ensure that the integrations users are setup correctly and all the steps leading up to "Connecting the clouds" are completed from the guide.

Then, log out of everything - both MC and Core.

Then, with API user credentials, log into MC and log into Core.

Try again - this should resolve it.

In case it doesn't, you can try to manually verify the remote site:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_advanced_faqs.htm&type=5